# Limit Supremum of Sequence Created by Interleaving 2 Bounded Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I'm studying for an upcoming departmental exam, and this was one of the questions given on a previous year's exam.

> Let $(a_{n})$ and $(b_{n})$ be real, bounded sequences, and let $(c_{n})$ be the sequence created by interleaving the terms of $(a_{n})$ and $(b_{n})$,
> $$(c_{n}) = (a_{1}, b_{1}, a_{2}, b_{2},\cdots)$$
> Prove that
> $$\limsup(c_{n})\leq \max\{\limsup(a_{n}), \limsup(b_{n})\}.$$
> Further, if both $(a_{n})$ and $(b_{n})$ both converge to $\gamma$, then $(c_{n})$ converges to $\gamma$ also.

The second part is pretty straightforward, no problems there. I've tried a couple of different things to solve the first part, mostly playing around with the various definition of $\limsup$ (supremum of subsequential limits, limit of the supremum of the $m$-tail, the "eventually less than $t$" definition, etc), as I am not sure one would work best here. What really confused me was at one point, I thought it should be the opposite, that the inequality should be reversed:

> If you let $A, B,$ and $C$ be the set of subsequential limits of $(a_{n}), (b_{n})$, and $(c_{n})$, respectively $(b_{n})$, then clearly, both $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq C$, as both $(a_{n})$ and $(b_{n})$ are already subsequences of $(c_{n})$. This would then imply that $\sup A\leq\sup C$ and $\sup B\leq\sup C$, and hence, that $\max\{\sup A, \sup B\}\leq\sup C$, which is the opposite of what we are to prove.

I'm probably completely wrong with this and missing something painfully obvious, but if anyone can come up with a proof of the original problem and tell me why my "proof" is wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Bonus points if you can use the first part to imply the second part, which is what I would imagine the test wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not done anything wrong. You just proved the easy inequality but you are asked to prove that the **reverse inequality is also true**.

Consider any subsequence of $(c_n)$. Then it includes a subsequence of $(a_n)$ or  it includes a subsequence of $(b_n)$. Can you use this to finish the proof?

Comment: Thanks, think I got it. Let $C$ be the set of subsequential limits of $(c_{n})$, let $c\in C$, and $(c_{n_{k}})$ be a convergent subsequence of $(c_{n})$ which converges to $c$. Then, because $(c_{n_{k}})$ contains infinitely many terms of $(c_{n})$, $(c_{n_{k}})$ itself must have a subsequence which equals a subsequence of either $(a_{n})$ or $(b_{n})$, and hence, either $(a_{n})$ or $(b_{n})$ has a subsequence which converges to $c$. Hence, $C\subseteq A\cup B$. Therefore $\sup C \leq \sup A\cup B = max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$, and we have our desired inequality. Sound good?

Comment: @ChrisAustin Yes, the argument is right.